# Why checkbox not visually update inside my Navigation component

Tags: reactjs

I'm making a Navigation component with various levels, but components inside it don't update visually, like checkbox and Switch components on my Codesandbox example. (I have the same Switch out of Navigation, it's updating visually)

The value from Switch and checkbox is updating, check the console.

I think that is any rerendering from Navigation, specific because of the context.

https://codesandbox.io/s/navigation-dgsnf

Some help is welcome, thank you guys